# Longest running unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

How can we find the junit tests in our suite that take the longest amount of time to run?  The default output of the junitreport ant task is helpful, but our suite has thousands of tests organized into many smaller suites, so it gets tedious, and the worst offenders are always changing.

We use luntbuild but ideally it would be something we could just run from ant.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to know?

One of my most useful jUnit tests takes a long time - not because the code is inefficient, but because it tests with a very exhaustive set of conditions (three for() loops deep)

Comment: We have a lot of poorly written tests.  Some do a lot of unnecessary set-up.  Some tests use Thread.sleep().  A few really need a long time to run.  Our suite takes a half hour to run and I'm looking for the easy targets to speed it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JUnitReport works on the xml files produced by the JUnit task. You could write a task that would read the test durations out of the same xml files (TEST-*.xml). But you can also take a shortcut and just read the summary file created by JUnitReport (TESTS-TestSuites.xml) which has all the information in the single file.

A quick way to do this is to use a bit of xsl to just show the slowest tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="testsuites/testsuite">
    <xsl:sort select="@time" data-type="number" order="descending" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> : <xsl:value-of select="@time"/>
      <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To run from Ant you do this:

```
<target name="show.slow.tests">
    <xslt in="target/tests-results/TESTS-TestSuites.xml" out="target/slow.txt" style="slow.xsl"/>
</target>
```

Then you can just look at the first X lines to find the X slowest tests:

jfredrick$ head target/slow.txt

  ForcingBuildShouldNotLockProjectInQueuedStateTest : 11.581
  CruiseControlControllerTest : 7.335
  AntBuilderTest : 6.512
  Maven2BuilderTest : 4.412
  CompositeBuilderTest : 2.222
  ModificationSetTest : 2.05
  NantBuilderTest : 2.04
  CruiseControlConfigTest : 1.747
  ProjectTest : 1.743
  BuildLoopMonitorTest : 0.913

Answer (score 2):

Use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). They have great reports, and version 4.0 even orders your tests so the most flaky tests run first.

Answer (score 1):

If you launch your tests on your build server using cruise control, it is one of the top level options to sort by run time.